# Singleton Connection Pattern for a Social Networking Site, Multiple Users

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, pdo

I have been reading about Singleton, and i managed to create a Connection Manager Class in PHP that uses a singleton, this enables my program/application to connect to the database, but i want to know since singleton connection pattern has one instance does this affect multiple users accessing the database at the same time. Say for a social networking site with large amount of traffic everyday, will there be connection issues due to large access by multiple users since all will be going through this one instance of connection, wont it also slow down the application?

Comment: it's difficult to explain, but the pattern only applies to your script lifetime. The singleton pattern prevents your code to instantiate several connections (mistake to be avoided). Concurrent call to your script will run different instances of php, and there's no perf issues

Comment: Regarding singletons, a singleton in PHP is a singleton _per request_. Every request (page request etc. same or different users) will have their own object through out that request. If they click on a link and load another page or refresh the current page, then it's a new request and your code will start from scratch. Objects aren't shared. Regarding _"will it be slow"_, that 100% depends on your code. The singleton pattern won't affect that.

Comment: what will you advice?, because what am working on is going to go LIVE and  will have a mobile app. I don't want a situation where an issue will affect an entire application

Comment: _"I don't want a situation where an issue will affect an entire application"_ - Nobody does, but it still happens. Advice? Be prepared for it to happen, learn to debug, benchmark to find where the performance issue is and then sort it out. It's impossible to answer that question with a "real" solution since there's 10000 (or even more) things that can affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton in PHP means you are using 1 instance of a class **per request**. Nothing to worry about, each user will have it's own request, and therefore a different instance of your singleton.

This doesn't mean you can't get into connection issues when you start getting more traffic. In my experience the number of database connections is usually the first bottleneck a web application runs into on a classic LAMP stack. But that has nothing to do with the usage of singletons, it is an infrastructure issue, which is entirely different topic, and not something a PHP developer should worry about imo.

Comment: Whew! Thanks Pevara, So i can just continue using my Singleton Connection Manager Class, and not worry about how many users accessing this single instance at the same time, and just be prepared for General issues,